# question ? An error occurred on the mail server

Tags: email, server, command

An error occurred on the mail server

- mail kernel : pid 1237 (mail.local), uid 1078 inumber 4022496 on /:filesystem full
- g_vfs_done() : da0p2[READ(offset=7265786478563734, length=73967)] error = 5

error message is constantly displayed on the console.

Comment: The g_vfs_done():da0s3f[READ(offset=-2048, length=16384)]error = 5 error message is constantly displayed on the console.

Comment: root@mail:/var/log # df -h Filesystem Size- 454G Used- 159G Avail- 259G

Answer (score 0):

Look likes that your server has out of space problem.

## df -h

It will show you all the files and how much space they are taking up. The only way out is deleting the files you do not need.

Comment: root@mail:/var/log # df -h
Filesystem    Size- 454G   Used- 159G  Avail- 259G

Comment: Show the out put of `# df -h /`